# How to wait a while before adding elements in css? javascript?

Tags: html, function, css, sleep, wait

I have a problem that I will explain. 
I'm doing an animation in HTML5 and CSS3. My idea is that a plane is flying around and it launches a missile after a while. What I want to do is to make the missile appear after that time. I thought about doing that changing the z-Index property of my div (because I have the missile image into a div container) using javascript after a while (any time I choose). For doing that I found the sleep function at the bottom. I created the "appear" function that I know it works because It changes my zIndex value but it doesn't wait the 2 seconds I want.

I also thought I had the solution by using the visibility property, but I have the same problem, sleep function doesn't wait at all.

Any suggestions? Thanks

```
    function sleep(milliseconds) {
      var start = new Date().getTime();
      for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
        if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    function appear(object){

    sleep(200000);
    var objective = document.getElementById(object);

    objective.style.zIndex=1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a function to the `setTimeout` function which will call that function in x milliseconds.

```
function waitForMe() {
    alert('triggered!');
}

// Call waitForMe in 200000ms
setTimeout(waitForMe, 200000);
```

So for your example, you would want to use 2000 (2 seconds), not 200000 (200 seconds):

```
function appear(object) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var objective = document.getElementById(object);
        objective.style.zIndex=1;
    }, 2000);
}
```

**Hiding and showing an element**

You can hide and show a method in a few ways:

1. Use `z-index` as you suggest, probably not the best way as we can actually hide it instead of sending it to the back of the page.

   ```
   objective.style.zIndex = 1;
   ```
2. Use `display`, this hide the object completely.

   ```
   // hide
   objective.style.display = 'none';
   // show
   objective.style.display = 'block';
   ```
3. Use `visibility`, this will hide the object but it will still take up space in the page. This wouldn't matter if you're using `position:fixed` or `position:absolute`.

   ```
   // hide
   objective.style.visibility = 'hidden';
   // show
   objective.style.visibility = 'visible';
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a div around the objective, and add it in with javascript like this

```
  document.getElementById('objectivespan').innerHTML=imagehere;
```

Other than that, you can use

```
  objective.style.visibility='hidden';
```

and change it to
      objective.style.visibility='visible';

for the delay, use

```
  function sleep(){
      alert('slept');
  }
  SetTimeout('sleep', 10000);
```